# How to render something in an if statement React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

### **Problem**

I am using a flatlist in react native, and want to compare to variables in the flatlist, and render a text component if the two variables are equal, but render nothing if they are not. I've tried many methods of doing this, but they nothing has worked. I would love some help figuring out a way to do this! Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give some detail information or something what you have done in your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple ways that spring to mind straight away. Ill just assume what you are trying to compare but you can switch these variables out for whatever you please. First thing you could do is have your text be conditional inside of your `Text` component, EG

```
<Text>{this.state.variable == this.props.stuff ? "RENDER TEXT" : ""}</Text>
```

or, if you want to emit the `Text` component when variables are not equal, have a function inside of your class that will return the `Text` component conditionally

```
renderMessage = () => {
    if(this.state.variable == "stuff"){
        return(
            <Text>They were equal</Text>
        );
    }else{
        return(
            <View></View> // OR WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
        );
    }
}
...
//Then in your render function
....
<View style = {styles.whatever}>
    {this.renderMessage()}
</View>
```

Comment: worth commenting: i'm not sure you can return null inside `renderMessage` but maybe you can - needs clarification

Answer (score 0):

just compare your data in renderItem method accordingly

```
 <FlatList
      data={this.props.data}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />

    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        if(item=='somthing'){
           return <Text> your test </Text>
         }else{
            return <Text>some other text</Text> 
         }
    );
```

if you want to compare your text in component then

```
<View>
    {
    item.data == 'somthing'
       ?
      <Text>if</Text> 
       :
      <Text>else</Text>
    }
</View>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this answer

Comment: This is not working. Requires some syntax corrections